# 90s/early 2000s animated Superman TV show episode in which Superman goes rogue under the influence of a sea star-like creature

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman, episode-identification, dc-animated-universe

Many years ago, I caught an episode of an animated Superman show done in the iconic Bruce Timm style of *Batman: The Animated Series*. I've tried to figure out if the episode was from a Justice League series, Superman's own title, or something else I don't remember.

Some details about the show follow, but I could be conflating more than one show. Or episodes of the same show, for that matter. All manner of apologies if so.

- Superman is working with a team of other superheroes to stop... some plot, and I didn't see the whole thing to know what it was.
- A missile - an ICBM, perhaps? - is launched, and the heroes have to stop it
- One character I didn't know (I think I remember wings and a red suit?) was pushing the missile and was in physical contact with it
- At some point...

  > the bomb detonates, vaporizing whoever the character was on the missile
- After viewing video footage of the event, it turns out...

  > Superman detonated the missile with his heat vision, deliberately murdering the other character.
- Wonder Woman (I believe) and some others go to Batman for help. When Batman sees the video footage, he...

  > gets a bit of kryptonite he's storing in the Batcave; when asked why he had it, he says, "He's gone rogue before," or something to that effect (not an exact quote)
- In the end, it turned out...

  > Supes had been suffocated to unconsciousness by an alien creature similar to a sea star. It took over his body and was using it to protect itself and position itself to take over the Earth.
- And it all started when...

  > Superman had to rescue a spaceship full of weird creatures taken by someone for their own amusement; a zoo, of sorts, basically. Some of the aliens in the ship, contained in simulated environments for each of them, were sapient...like the sea star. Superman couldn't return them home because whoever owned the ship was...killed, maybe? during the fight with Supes, and he didn't know where they'd all come from, let alone how to get them back to wherever they came from. So he kept the ship under his Fortress of Solitude.
- It was at least a two-part episode of the show.

That's about all I can recall, and the details, again, could be off, or at least a conflation of other shows/episodes of the same show. But my Google-Fu fails me whenever I try to find it online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the two-part episode ["The Call"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519434/) from *Batman Beyond* (2000).

**Superman is working with a team of other superheroes to stop... some plot**

Explosions, burning city, civilians in distress, just another day at the job. See video above (beginning).

**One character I didn't know (I think I remember wings and a red suit?) was pushing the missile and was in physical contact with it.**

That's Warhawk, son of Hawkgirl. You can see him trying to slow down the missile in the video above (2'04). He does have metallic wings, as well as red stripes on his outfit.

**the bomb detonates, vaporizing whoever the character was on the missile**

Timestamp is 2'23, when Warhawk's helmet is thrown away by the explosion and lands on Batman's cockpit window.

**After viewing video footage of the event, it turns out Superman detonated the missile with his heat vision, deliberately murdering the other character.**

Timestamp is 3'41: Bruce Wayne realizes the ICBM was hit with a laserlike ray, does fancy footage manipulation and reveals Superman used his heat vision on it.

**When Batman sees the video footage, he gets a bit of kryptonite he's storing in the Batcave; when asked why he had it, he says, "He's gone rogue before,"**

Timestamp is 4'30:

> This isn't the first time Superman's gone rogue. I made sure to be prepared for when it happens again. I prayed I'd never have to use it.

**Supes had been suffocated to unconsciousness by an alien creature similar to a sea star. It took over his body and was using it to protect itself and position itself to take over the Earth.**

The "sea star" you were remembering is Starro, a notorious starfish with telepathic/mind-control powers.

**Superman had to rescue a spaceship full of weird creatures taken by someone for their own amusement**

Starro's origin is detailed in the video below. Long story short, it matched quite what you remembered: Starro was "collected" by The Preserver, along with other creatures; Superman got collected too but broke free and, not being able to return them to their home, hosted them in the Fortress of Solitude.

Problem being, Starro eventually jumped on him, and had been manipulating him for *years*. End goal being controlling the world, and Superman's powers come handy in plans like that.

---

Found with the Google query `superman batman starro cartoon` which returned [Starro's page on the DCAU wikia](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Starro). I used the `starro` keyword as the question mentioned a "sea star", and Starro is the only starfish character (of importance) that I know in the DC universe.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was beginning to think I'd imagined the whole thing! Well done!

Comment: @Josh you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :D